# getting the value of multiple checkboxes and using ajax to preform an action with their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that has checkboxes, if a checkbox is selected i want a raw in the DB to be deleted - using ajax.

with normal form i would simply name all the chexboxs some name lets say name="checkbox[]"
and then simply use foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value){}

now i am trying to get all the values of marked checkboxes then put them into an array. seems i am missing something though. here is what i go so far:

```
var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
var temp = new Array();
jQuery.each(checkboxes, function(key, value) { 
     temp[] = value;
});
```

Late on i will just pass temp as variable to ajax call.

Is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: Note that JavaScript is _not_ Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over the Checkbox values which is wrong . Try this

```
var $checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]') ;
var temp = new Array();
jQuery.each($checkboxes, function(i) {
     var value = $(this).attr('value'); 
     temp[i] = value;
});
```

If you want to pass only checked items just add a condition.

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  var value = $(this).attr('value'); 
  temp[i] = value;
}
```

Comment: Check out jQuery.map(), it's a better fit for this task than jQuery.each().

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:checked` selector and `map` method:

```
var arr = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
     return this.value
}).get();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the chained .get()? .map will return an array.

Comment: @MattStone map returns a jquery-wrapped array, get returns the actual array.

Comment: are you sure about that? The documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) or a quick test (http://jsfiddle.net/2aSdZ/) doesn't indicate that's the case.

Comment: @MattStone Yes, what you are using is $.map utility function and I have used this map http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: @MattStone See this http://jsfiddle.net/k96VX/ without get you will have _TypeError: arr.join is not a function_

Comment: Good point. Without .get() it still certainly _looks_ like an array, but it doesn't one. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the table in a form tag, and do this:

```
var myData = jQuery('#myform').serialize();
jQuery.ajax('myscript.php', {data:myData});
```